# Blender selection in viewport suddenly slow (68 faces)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, 3d-view, transforms, performance

I have been working on this .blend project for a couple of week now, and suddenly, I noticed it became SUPER slow. I pinpointed that the drop in frames happens when I select a new object and try to scale it. After I try scaling the object for a couple of seconds, it seems whatever is causing the drop in frames goes away. Here is the [.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/f6c4aff28afe401b8dc4b8bd76aa8500).

I captured what I am experiencing:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to replicate this on my hw, what processor and GPU are you using?